# No puedo insertar datos a MYSQL si utilizo el action en HTML para ir a pagina

Tags: php, html, mysql

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
<form method="post" action="ingre_acta_exi.php">
  <table class="table bg-info" id="tabla">
    <tr class="fila-fija">
      <td><input type="number" name="IDE[]" id="IDE" value=""/></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="PLANILLA[]" id="PLANILLA" pattern="[0-9]{6}" value=""/></td>
      <td><input value="" type="text" name="N_PEDIDO[]" id="N_PEDIDO"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="btn-der">
    <button id="adicional" name="adicional" type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Agregar</button>
    <input type="submit" name="insertar" id="insertar" value="Insertar" class="btn btn-info"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['insertar']))
{
  $items2 = ($_POST['IDE']);
  $items3 = ($_POST['PLANILLA']);
  $items4 = ($_POST['N_PEDIDO']);

  while(true){

    //Recuperar los valores de los arreglos
    $item2 = current($items2);
    $item3 = current($items3);
    $item4 = current($items4);

    $valores ='('.$ide.',"'.$planilla.'","'.$n_pedido.'"),';

    $valoresQ = substr($valores, 0, -1);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO huawei_acta_entrega (IDE, PLANILLA, N_PEDIDO) 
    VALUES $valoresQ";

    $sqlRes = mysql_query($sql, $conexion) or mysql_error();

    $item2 = next($items2);
    $item3 = next($items3);
    $item4 = next($items4);

    if($item2 === false && $item3 === false && $item4 === false && $item5 === 
    false && $item6 === false && $item7 === false && $item8 === false && $item9 
    === false && $item10 === false && $item11 === false) break;
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: No me queda claro qué valores quieres subir a la base de datos. Ingresa por favor también los valores de la BD

Comment: Es un formulario, en donde en `IDE` ingreso un valor numérico entero, en `PLANILLA` y `N_PEDIDO` un valor tipo varchar.

Comment: Hola @AnderssonViverosMartinez, ¿Te tira algún error? ¿Compruebas que estás enviando bien los parametros? ¿Por qué le añades una "**,**" y luego se la quitas?

Comment: mientras sea true? creo que el while(true) es el del problema

Comment: Hola Edu3D, no me arroja ningún error y la coma es para poder concatenar los valores que paso por POST ya que son varias filas las que inserto a la vez, respecto al while, vaavDev, no estoy seguro que sea eso, el punto es que cuando yo quito la dirección del `action` me deja insertar datos a la BD correctamente, pero obviamente no puedo redireccionar a la pagina que quiero.

Comment: ¿Por qué haces un bucle "infinito"? Si falla esa inserción te revienta la página. Te sobra el while true.

Comment: Para poder insertar varias filas con u n solo submit, la verdad no se como hacerlo de otra forma.

Comment: @AnderssonViverosMartinez Vale, me acabo de fijar, mira bien esto: `$item2 = current($items2);
$item3 = current($items3);
$item4 = current($items4);

 $valores ='('.$ide.',"'.$planilla.'","'.$n_pedido.'"),';`  Fijate en el nombre de las variables y de las que usas en **$valores**

Comment: Se que no tengo mucho conocimiento en esto, pero el código para el requerimiento funciona bien es decir inserta correctamente, lo que no puedo hacer es que me redireccione cuando hago clic y se activa el submit.

Comment: @AnderssonViverosMartinez, pues no estoy entendiendo bien la pregunta... Puedes intentar plantearla de otra forma? explicar algo más de lo que hace y lo que esperas que haga

Comment: el php lo tienes en el mismo documento? por lo que te entendí todo eso que subiste (html y php )lo tienes en un mismo archivo y quieres que al insertar redireccione al documento del action? es así como lo tienes?

Comment: asi es  Sergio1871, los dos códigos están en un mismo archivo, quiero al insertar me redireccione a otra pagina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final del código PHP de insertar (luego de cerrar el `while`) podrías hacer una redirección utilizando [`header`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php), así:

```
if(isset($_POST['insertar']))
{
  ...
  }// Llave que cierra el while
  header('Location: /pagina.php');
}
```

Comment: Piyin Muchas gracias, era lo que necesitaba.